# ImportError: Cannot import name monotonic

Tags: python, python-import

Right now I'm sitting on a blank file which consists only of the following:

```
import os
import sys
import shlex
import subprocess
import signal
from time import monotonic as timer
```

I get this error when I try to run my file: ImportError: Cannot import name monotonic
If it matters, I am on linux and my python ver is 2.7.16 - I can't really change any of this because I'm working from my school server... What exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Python 2.x does not have `monotonic` it available from python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function only exists in Python 3. For Python 2, you can use the external [monotonic module](https://pypi.org/project/monotonic/). After that, you can use it as

```
from monotonic import monotonic as timer

timer()
```

However, note that its values differ from those returned by the Python 3 function (e.g. on macOS it uses [`mach_absolute_time`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1462446-mach_absolute_time), which is “starting at an arbitrary point”).

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic

`time.monotonic()` is available since Python 3.3, you can't have it with 2.7